# Python Django Web Application issue

Tags: django-models

I have created a user creation page and forget password page. all the fields are created in models.py and i want to show the forgot password through HttpResponse when the user clicks of submit button forgot password page. Please help how to get it.

```
models.py as in my project
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class NewUser(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    lname=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address=models.TextField()
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    pwd=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    cpwd=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    cell=models.CharField(max_length=10)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email

views.py as in my project
def forgot_pwd(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    email_id=request.POST.get('userid','')
    print email_id
    rec_mail_id=NewUser.objects.get(email=email_id)
    print rec_mail_id
    if rec_mail_id:
        rec_pwd=NewUser.objects.get(pwd)
        return HttpResponse("Your password is %s" %rec_pwd)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("You are not yet registered\n   <a href=/CreateUser>Please click here to register</a>")
else:
        return render_to_response('forgot_pwd.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Can you post your models.py and views.py you have written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`models.py` should be :

```
class user_registration(models.Model):
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=500,blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
```

`views.py` should be :

def checkRegistration(request):

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email_id']
        getpassword = user_registration.objects.get(email_id=email)
        print getpassword.password
        "Manuculate with getpassword as you want"

else:
     "Do whatever you want"
```

`form.py` should be :

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import data


class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user_registration
        fields = [
                  "email_id",
                  "password"
                  ]
```

Comment: Hi, i have not used any forms.py